# Parsing a text file with date headings and multiple entries

Tags: python, string, dictionary, parsing, text

I've been trying to parse a large text file I have and convert it into a dictionary for further analysis. Here's a sample of the text file:

```
Mar 2 (2020, year not always present)
first paragraph
second line of first paragraph

second paragraph
second line of second paragraph

Mar 3
More lines
these two should be grouped together
because they don't have a blank line in between them

however this line is a start of a new "entry"

sometimes they only have one line, sometimes many.
```

Idealy, this would produce the following Python dictionary:

```
{"Mar 2": ["first paragraph\nsecond line of first paragraph", "second paragraph\nsecond line of second paragraph"], "Mar 3": ["More lines\nthese two should be grouped together\nbecause they\ndon't have a blank line in between them", "however this line is a start of a new \"entry\"", "sometimes they only have one line, sometimes many."]}
```

I've tried using the following code and it almost works but I'm not sure what's wrong.

```py
def isdate(line):
    return line.lower().split(" ")[0] in ("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sept", "oct", "nov", "dec")

data = ...

lines = data.split("\n")
i = 0
data = {}
while i < len(lines):
    if isdate(lines[i]):
        date = lines[i]
        data[date] = []
        i += 1
        while not isdate(lines[i]):
            curr_d = ""
            while lines[i].strip(" ") != "":
                curr_d += lines[i] + "\n"
                i += 1
            i += 1
            data[date].append(curr_d)
    else:
        print("error in parsing")
        break
```

The problem with my code is that it outputs the correct data **however** it crashes when it reaches the end. Sorry for not including this earlier, I only just realised that it in fact does output the correct data but just crashes.

I don't think this is a duplicate, although it is very hard to search for something this specific yet this general (if you see what I mean), although I'm sure some SO wizzards out there will correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I've tried using the following code and it almost works but I'm not sure what's wrong.`. You need to provide expected output and actual output

Comment: @JammyDodger OK I will do that promptly

Comment: @JammyDodger Well I just re-checked on my code and now I've realised that it works but just crashes at the end (index out of range). Should I close this question, as I think I should be able to fix it on my own now?

Comment: If you do, include the fix in case someone else has this problem

Comment: Crashes how? Do you get a traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def isdate(line):
    return line.lower().split(" ")[0] in ("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sept", "oct", "nov", "dec")

with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = {}
line_concat = ""
for line in lines:
    if isdate(line): # new key
        if line_concat: # save previous element to old data point
            data[key].append(line_concat)
        month, day = line.split(" ")[0:2]
        key = month+" "+day
        data[key] = []
        continue
    if line.strip(): # if not empty line
        line_concat += line # add line to actual value as memory
    else:
        data[key].append(line_concat) # add the element to the list
        line_concat = "" # set memory empty
data[key].append(line_concat)
for d in data:
    print(d,data[d])
```

## Output:

```
Mar 2 ['first paragraph\nsecond line of first paragraph\n', 'second paragraph\nsecond line of second paragraph\n']
Mar 3
 ["More lines\nthese two should be grouped together\nbecause they don't have a blank line in between them\n", 'however this line is a start of a new "entry"\n', 'sometimes they only have one line, sometimes many.']
```